# MySQL does not retrieve first item in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've now been trying for hour and can't figure the problem out. I've made a php file that fetch all items in a table and retrieves that as JSON. But for some reason after I inserted the second mysql-query, it stopped fetching the first item. My code is following:

```
...
    case "LoadEntryList":
        $result2 = performquery("SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Category = '" . $_POST["Category"] .
        "' LIMIT " . $_POST["Offset"] . ", " . $_POST["Quantity"] . "");
        $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result3 = performquery("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE ID = '" . $row2["UserID"] . "'");
        $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
   echo substr(json_encode($row),0,
        strlen(json_encode($row))-1) . ",\"Username\":\"" . $row3["Username"]  . "\"}";
}
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for all those super fast responses.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry I used ORDER BY 'ID' ASC and it gave me an error...

Comment: @Fusseldieb ORDER BY ID ASC, without the quote. Also I don't mean to rant or anything, but beside the wide sql inject, it's also messy and poorly written. Query inside a loop, is also a bad thing, avoid where possible. Use a left join on `Entries` and `Users`. Your manually editing the json string. Don't! Before you encode it add to your `$row` another index `$row['Username'] = $row3['Username']` and then encode it. Limit $result3 query to 1.

Comment: @Strawberry How do I join the two queries to retrieve a entry and then replace the UserID with the username in one query? The only solution I found by myself is that... And the injection, don't worry, I sanitize the inputs normally later, its just for debugging now...

Comment: @Fusseldieb 'ID' is a string. ID or \`ID\` might be a column name. And you only need one query here. The accepted answer is poor.

Comment: not only that, but there is a problem with the encoded json as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need of `$row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();`

```
    <?
    case "LoadEntryList":
    $result2 = performquery("SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Category = '" . $_POST["Category"] .
        "' LIMIT " . $_POST["Offset"] . ", " . $_POST["Quantity"] . "");
    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $result3 = performquery("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE ID = '" . $row["UserID"] . "'");
        $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
        echo substr(json_encode($row),0,strlen(json_encode($row))-1) . ",\"Username\":\"" . $row3["Username"]  . "\"}";
    }
    ?>
```

Or,

```
<?
...
    case "LoadEntryList":
    $Category=$_POST["Category"];
    $Offset=$_POST["Offset"];
    $Quantity=$_POST["Quantity"];

    $result3 = performquery("SELECT Entries.*, Users.Username FROM Entries, Users WHERE Entries.Category=$Category AND Entries.UserID=Users.ID LIMIT $Offset, $Quantity");

    $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
    echo substr(json_encode($row),0,strlen(json_encode($row))-1) . ",\"Username\":\"" . $row3["Username"]  . "\"}";
}
...
?>
```

Comment: It actually solved my problem almost instantly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad It Helped Mr @Fusseldieb. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain about the downvote ?? Don't simply downvote and escape by hiding faces.

Comment: I don't know who down voted, but you fixed a small portion of a bad written code. You should have updated the code to fix all of his issues. Don't support poorly written code, fix it or suggest something else so they can learn.

Comment: Mr @MujnoiGyulaTamas : As OP wrote `Thanks, I know about this injection attack. Its just for the debug for now... Normally I sanitize the inputs. – Fusseldieb` To Mr David . He was only interested in knowing the problem why he is getting only one row. I did that. Simple.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I'm not talking about the sanitizing part because I saw the comment as well. It's about the query. Join the 2 queries, eliminating 1 extra query, also the need to substr which is eliminated if prior the encode you add it to the array $row, see my answer for more details

Comment: @Fusseldieb : For JOIN : See My Updated Answer. You can reduce 2 query in one single query.

Answer (score 3):

First you're fetching a row:

```
$row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
```

Then you start looping at the next row:

```
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
```

If you want to loop over all of the rows, don't skip the first one.  Just loop over all of the rows:

```
$result2 = // your very SQL-injectable query
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
  $result3 = // your other very SQL-injectable query
  $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
  // etc.
}
```

Note that errors like this would be a *lot* more obvious if you used meaningful variable names.  "row2", "result3", etc. are pretty confusing when you have overlapping levels of abstraction.

---

**Important:** Your code is *wide open* to ***SQL injection attacks***.  You're basically allowing users to execute any code they want on your database.  Please look into using prepared statements and treating user input as *values* rather than as *executable code*.  [This](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) is a good place to start reading, as is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks, I know about this injection attack. Its just for the debug for now... Normally I sanitize the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I have a addition to David answer(can't comment on it yet)

This line of code:

```
   $result3 = performquery("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE ID = '" . $row2["UserID"] . "'");
```

will always return with the same result. If you were to change `$row2[...` into `$row[...` the code would take the rows that get updated by the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not content with the accepted result. The snippet can be **fixed / replaced**, and also a bad code must be replaced. Also not to mention is that I don't know if anyone spotted a really big mistake in the output. Here is the fix and I'll explain why.

```
$JSON = array();
$result2 = performquery( '
    SELECT
        e.*, u.Username
    FROM Entries AS e
    LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.ID = e.UserID
    WHERE
        e.Category = ' . $_POST['Category'] . '
    LIMIT ' . $_POST['Offset'] . ', ' . $_POST['Quantity'] . '
' );
while( $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc() ){
    $JSON[] = $row2;
}
echo json_encode( $JSON );
```

Obviously the main issue is the query, so I fixed it with a `LEFT JOIN`, now the second part is the output. First it's the way you include the username, and the second what if you had multiple results? Than your output will be:

```js
{"ID":1,"Username":"John"}{"ID":2,"Username":"Doe"}
```

How do you parse it? So the `$JSON` part comes in place. You add it to an array and will encode that array. Now the result is:

```
{["ID":1,"Username":"John"],["ID":2,"Username":"Doe"]}
```

**LE:** I left out the sql inject part which as stated by the OP, will be done afterwards? I'm not sure why not do it at the point of writing it, because you may forget later on that you need to sanitize it.

Comment: SQL injection I'm preventing now by converting some string into integers.... limiting string length.... etc.

Comment: As mentioned previously you should use prepared statments. also make sure you don't run into the second problem I mentioned.

Comment: For the output I use replace "}{" to "},{"... And your code gives me an 500 error, I don't know why...

Comment: I missed a column identifier, my mistake. `Category` should be `e.Category`. I updated my answer. Also why search and replace, because you can simply add it to an array prior encodeing it with json_encode.

Comment: @Fusseldieb replacing what you described may still cause error your final result will be `{"ID":1,"Username":"John"},{"ID":2,"Username":"Doe"}`, which isn't wrapped in anything, thus you still have multiple objects. You should than wrap all the replaces in a wrapper like `echo '{', substr(json_encode($row),0,strlen(json_encode($row))-1) . ",\"Username\":\"" . $row3["Username"]  . "\"}}";`, but its just a waste of resource and bad practise. I'm not trying to be a bad person, I'm just trying to help you realise and code in a more efficient and cleaner way. Hope you don't take it the wrong way.

Comment: I have taken your updated code, it gave me 500 error too, then I've put a quotation mark between "Category" and now it seems to work. Thanks very much.

Comment: EDIT: Yes, now it works. And I agree, It's much cleaner now. Thanks!!